# Breaking a file down and rewriting it in java

Tags: java, string, file, io

I'm working on trying to break down this file that contains state abbreviations, state names, and zip codes. Some of the zip codes are only 3 digit zip codes and for formatting purposes have to be rewritten(Ex. 005 should be 005-005). What I need help with is separating the state names and abbreviations from the zip codes so that I can format the 3 digit zip codes into 6 digit zip codes.

The layout of the file is like this:

NY New York 005 063 090-149

etc with the rest of the states... (Notice how New York is a 2 part name and how it has a 3 digit zip code of 005 and 063. That needs to be rewritten as 005-005 and 063-063)

Here is my code:

```
    public class ZipsReader {
public static void main(String[] args){

    //Gets the file name and reads it
    try {
        //Prompts user for an input file
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input file: ");
        String inputFileName = console.next();

        //Prompts user for an output file
        //System.out.println("Output file: ");
        //String outputFileName = console.next();
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

        //Reads the selected file line for line
        File selectedFile = new File(inputFileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(selectedFile);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            Scanner in2 = new Scanner(line);

            //Reads the selected file word for word
            while (in2.hasNext()){
                String state = in2.isLetter();
                String word = in2.next();
                    if (word.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}")){
                        System.out.println(word);
                    }
                        if (word.matches("\\d{3}")){
                            System.out.println(word + "-" + word);
                        }
            }
            in2.close();//closes the word scanner
        }
        console.close();//closes the file opener scanner
        in.close();//closes the line scanner
        //out.close();//closes the print writer
    }

    //Prints out message if file cant be found
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry the file could not be found.");
    }

    //Needed to compile
    finally {
    }
}
```

}

The .matches String method works for getting the zip codes but I am not sure how to pick out the state abbrev. and names separately from the zip codes.

Right now I am just doing it to the console for time saving reasons for the time being but I will modify it to write to another file when I get this figured out.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public class ZipReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Gets the file name and reads it
    try {
        //Prompts user for an input file
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input file: ");
        String inputFileName = "G:\\test.txt";

    //Prompts user for an output file
        //System.out.println("Output file: ");
        //String outputFileName = console.next();
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
        //Reads the selected file line for line
        File selectedFile = new File(inputFileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(selectedFile);
        String states="";
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            Scanner in2 = new Scanner(line);

            //Reads the selected file word for word
            while (in2.hasNext()) {
                //String state = in2.isLetter();
                String word = in2.next();
                if (word.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}")) {
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
                else if (word.matches("\\d{3}")) {
                    System.out.println(word + "-" + word);
                }
                else if(word.matches("[A-Z]{2}")){
                    System.out.println(word);
                }

                else{
                    states=states+word+" ";
                }
            }
            System.out.println(states+"\n");
            states="";
            in2.close();//closes the word scanner
        }
        console.close();//closes the file opener scanner
        in.close();//closes the line scanner
        //out.close();//closes the print writer
    } //Prints out message if file cant be found
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry the file could not be found.");
    } //Needed to compile
    finally {
    }
  }
}
```